# How to set a maximum resolution of DAM image asset in AEM?

Tags: aem, dam

I am trying to set a limit to maximum resolution for image asset uploading in DAM. I understand that we can set a maximum size for uploading the assets, but I was wondering how do I set a specific highest resolution.

The only solution that I can think of is that ImageHelper can be used while running the **DAM Update Asset** workflow to check for the image dimension and in that case after checking the dimension, we can delete the asset if it is higher than the dimension. However, with this process the image is already uploaded to AEM first and then we are removing it DAM update asset workflow process.

Would appreciate any heads up on how I should approach this.

Comment: This article could be useful https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/How-to-restrict-the-file-size-of-uploads-in-Touch-UI-and-Classic-UI-AEM.html, they restrict uploading using size of asset, read about limitation for Classic UI, there is custom implementation used, may be you will get an idea how to implement it for resolution

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to get the max width and height of actual image and most probably you have to deal with the inputstreams and render the resolution with your custom service.

Thanks
Abhishek